# Installing and configuring Trac

Tags: svn, trac

I have a bunch of SVN repositories on my server and I'm wanting to install [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) on in order to view the source of the repositories

I got Trac from github and I'm running `1.1.2-dev`

I installed subversion via `yum install subversion` and created a basic subversion repository

I have then created a trac project

Now, what i want is to be able to view the repository within trac.

So, I edited `trac.ini` and added the following:

```
repository_dir = /path/to/my/repo

[components]
tracopt.versioncontrol.svn.* = enabled
```

But this gives me the folloowing error:

> Warning: Can't synchronize with repository "(default)" (Unsupported
>   version control system "svn": /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs_base-1.so.0:
>   undefined symbol: svn_fs__path_change2_create). Look in the Trac log
>   for more information.

I'm running CentOS6 and I cannot seem to find out why this is occuring.

Comment: looks like `svn_fs__path_change2_create` has been renamed to `svn_fs__path_change_create_internal` in subversion libs in 2009. But I don't know why that is a problem on your server.

Comment: I was hoping the post would be moved to serverfault. I originally built svn from source following this: http://djlab.com/2011/04/subversion-subversion-cpanel-whm/

Comment: I have  alog file: http://pastie.org/6412949

Comment: It might be related to the pysvn or subversion package installed. But I do not how to check that on CentOS.

Comment: I think it might be because I originally built subversion from source. Then I installed the yum package. I might have to remove the subversion files from the build

Comment: I don't have pysvn installed, only subversion and mod_python

Comment: I think I'll re-install subversion from source and compile the python bindings as well

Comment: I think you do need pysvn. But if you have fixed it, you can post the answer yourself and mark the question as answered.

Comment: You definitely don't need PySVN, you do need Subversion and its Python bindings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Trac 1.0.11) it was fixed by simply adding

```
tracopt.versioncontrol.svn.svn_fs.subversionconnector = enabled
```

to the [components] section in trac.ini

Took me a week to find out though.....